# “Thank you for considering my application” in Italian

Tags: phrase-request, letter-writing

When wrapping up an application in English, I like to conclude with the sentence "Thank you for considering my application".

I am now writing a Masters application to an Italian University, and I would like to do something similar.

Is there a standard turn of phrase in Italian corresponding to the English "Thank you for considering my application"?

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!

Comment: [Translation requests are off-topic here.](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/are-questions-about-translation-requests-on-topic)

Comment: @DaG Translation requests are indeed off-topic, but I think this question could be easily rephrased as asking for a customary formula in Italian correspondence, which should be perfectly on topic.

Comment: @JScripter I took the liberty of rewriting the question so to put it more in line with this site. Please correct it if you feel I changed the sense of your question.

Comment: @DenisNardin, in what does exactly this differ from a request translation, even with the new phrasing? What is a translation, if not finding “turns of phrase in [a language] corresponding to [the source language]”? If I understand correctly, what you have in mind is something like, say, “Yours sincerely” > “Distinti saluti”, but this is exactly what translating means.

Comment: @DaG The main difference for me is that those expressions are highly ritualized and so it is more "find a good Italian equivalent for this word" than "translate this paragraph", I (perhaps mistakenly) believed that the second case was off topic, not so the first.

Comment: A generic common courtesy phrase could be "La ringrazio per la cortese attenzione".
In this specific case maybe: "La ringrazio per la cortese attenzione nei riguardi della mia candidatura"

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Could you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

A generic common courtesy phrase that could be added as conclusion could be

> "La ringrazio per la cortese attenzione."

In this specific case I think I would write:

> "La ringrazio per la cortese attenzione nei riguardi della mia
>   candidatura."